# richtextbox shift + tab indent

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, indentation

I have a Windows Form in C# with a richtextbox and 2 buttons.

Button 1 with the below code. This works as it should when pressing tab.

```
GetRichTextBox().Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
```

Button 2 with the below code. This doesn't work and is doing the same as button 1. It is nowtreversing the tab.

```
GetRichTextBox().Focus();
SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}");
```

How can I resolve this issue please.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Are you trying to remove the tab?

Comment: button 1 should add a tab indent (this works as it should)
button 2 should do the reverse and remove the tab indent, but it doesn't.

This also doesn't work with notepad but it works with notepadd++

Comment: `SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");`  Not a fan of using SendKeys though.  You are assuming the cursor is always positioned correctly.  You can add a tab through code by `GetRichTextBox().SelectedText = "\t";`

Comment: I thought SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}"); was a good alternative, but then it also deletes the text/characters. I'm more interested in removing the tab. When using Scintilla it works, but I don't want to use Scintilla.

Comment: It only deletes the tab in my test.

Comment: On a richtextbox, from the left hand side, if you --> tab indent --> some text --> then backspace is deleting the text

Comment: Then you are doing something I can't see, like highlighting multiple characters or something.